# How to compute deterministic policy gradients in DDPG?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am writing a MATLAB script that uses Deep Determininstic Policy Gradient to control an Active Suspension System (Dynamic System), but I am stuck on updating the actor network. All of the examples and articles I read, use tensorflow libraries like tf.gradients(). However, I need to know exactly how to apply chain rule to compute the deterministic policy gradient shown in the image to implement it in my MATLAB code.

[image]